# XMLRPC and Nodes

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a single XMLRPC server running for all of the topics that are registered under a given node? Or does each topic maintain its own server? If there is a single XMLRPC server for all of the topics, at what point does communication switch to the new connection between subscriber/publisher -- is it immediately after the requesting the topic or does the connection header get exchanged first?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107241/xmlrpc-and-nodes/) by [chris-smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/6561/chris-smith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's one XMLRPC server per node. The XMLRPC communication is documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0